# What does the file cpuid.h do?

Tags: compiling, gcc

I am trying to build GLIBC 2.14 from source. I keep getting the error message that cpuid.h was not found.

What does that file contain and what purpose does it serve ?

I have seen that cpuid.h is placed in two different locations ie.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.3.0/include/cpuid.h
/usr/src/kernels/2.6.25-14.fc9.x86_64/include/config/x86/cpuid.h
```

Also I have seen that these two files are different running a simple diff tells me that -:

```
diff --brief /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.3.0/include/cpuid.h /usr/src/kernels/2.6.25-14.fc9.x86_64/include/config/x86/cpuid.h
Files /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.3.0/include/cpuid.h and /usr/src/kernels/2.6.25-14.fc9.x86_64/include/config/x86/cpuid.h differ
```

**What is cpuid.h, what does it normally contain and what purpose does it serve ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cpuid.h` contains definitions of assembly-language fragments to get low-level info out of certain CPUs, plus names for various numeric constants that a program might use to figure out what kind of CPU it was running on, and what features are available.  (For example, if the program wanted to use special matrix-math instructions available on some CPUs, it could check whether the instructions were available before trying to use them.  If the program was running on an older CPU, it could use software emulation of those instructions instead.)

The quick-n-dirty way to move ahead in your compilation project is just to copy one of the `cpuid.h` files you've found to a place where the compiler can find it.  (Maybe try `cp /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.3.0/include/cpuid.h /usr/include`)  It might not be the *right* file for your CPU, but most library routines don't need the cpuid information anyway, so it may let you make useful progress.  However, the library you build might not work in 100% of the places you expect it to, if you ever hit a function that tries to look up CPU info.

Comment: M: Your quick and dirty fix is exactly what I did before. Compilation worked but I wanted to know more about what this file was, so I posted the question here.

Comment: Ah, got it.  Take a look in the file -- they're well-commented, and any version will explain what's going on.  For example, the version on my Debian machine defines readable names corresponding to various bits in CPU registers, where the bits say whether the CPU supports MMX, SSE3, AES, and so forth.  Further down, there are some 32-bit signature values that correspond to various types of CPUs (AMD, INTEL, Cyrix, VIA, etc.)  After that are assembly-language snippets to do low-level things efficiently on various CPUs.

Comment: You can also get an idea of what's in there by `cat`ting `/proc/cpuinfo` -- that file contains a human-readable version of information pulled from the CPU.